# Attach PDF file to email via CURL PHP

Tags: php, pdf, curl, phpmailer

I want to attach a PDF file to the mail via CURL response.

I have an URL which prompts to download the file woth Ok button (Windows default).

I have tried below code snippets but no luck..

```
$hCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+'));
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_PUT,            true);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER,         true);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_URL,            "http://exampe.com/invoice/41/download");

$fp = fopen ($finfo['tmp_name'], "r");
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_INFILE,         $fp);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE,     $finfo['size']);

$sResp = curl_exec($hCurl);
rewind($verbose);
$debug = "Verbose info:\n<pre>" . htmlspecialchars(stream_get_contents($verbose)) ."</pre>";
echo $finfo['tmp_name'];
fclose($verbose);
curl_close($hCurl);
```

**AND**

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://exampe.com/invoice/41/download");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$file = fopen($output, 'r');
$size = filesize($output);
$fildata = fread($file,$size);
curl_close($ch);
```

And then tried to add response with

> $mail->addAttachment($response);

I wonder if i can ever do it or if i am doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Where's `$response` defined? And `$output` will contain the data from the download, not a file path?

Comment: $response is $sResp for first code and it is $filedata for second code.

Comment: If $output will contain data from download then how can i attach that pdf in email

Comment: Write it to a file (with e.g. file_put_contents), attach the file.

Comment: Any example will be more helpful

Comment: http://php.net/file_put_contents <-- examples in the docs.

Comment: But my url returns pdf file to download. I m nt pretty sure if u sounds right